How to activate/install a USB to "Gigabit" wired ethernet adapter in 24.04 LTS?
I have looked at the answers from 2013 and 2011 to similar questions.  There have been significant changes in Ubuntu from that epoch such that I will not attempt solutions from a decade past that involve system "internals" and hardware/software drivers.
The system was Scientific Linux 7, last release.  SL7 was a Fermilab/CERN clone of RHEL7.  The enduser needs a Zoom client.  Zoom will not work with older Zoom clients, and the current Zoom client will not work with SL7.  Rather than try a CentOS or other RHEL system that requires a complete reinstall, I did try and then install of 24.04.1 from the installation medium.  Neither try nor install "saw" the wired ethernet (the machine is a desktop without wifi -- no 802.11 interface).  I did save the /home from the SL7 system to media (the SL7 system did not use regular partitions but rather LVM) and I did construct a report on what the SL7 system saw for the 802.3 connection before booting the 24.04.1 try/install media.
The SL7 system reported the ethernet to USB adapter as an ASIX AX88179.  The adapter box using the AX88179 is a j5create JUE130 https://en.j5create.com/pages/drivers#jue130 for which the j5create URL does not show any Linux driver nor Linux installation instructions.

Assuming I can find the device from lsusb, what do I do next?

Which files need to be added/modified and where (directory path) to enable the JUE130 as the ethernet interface/adapter ("NIC") for the system?

Which processes need to be restarted to find the USB device for an ethernet interface once the needed files are in place?

If not files, which commands from a terminal CLI (bash)?

Is there a GUI that will accomplish this?

How do I force the automatic start of the JUE130 at every boot?


Any help would be appreciated.  Note that the LAN to which the adapter is connected is security controlled by physical wall connection and if the MAC address is changed (different ethernet USB adapter or internal ethernet card), the wall connection automatically is disabled until a systems technician controlling the router/s to which the physical connection is made re-enables the wall connection, something over which neither I nor the end user has any control.  Note that the university at which the machine is located permits the end user to install and run Linux, but only provides support for MS Windows and Mac OS X, and then only versions and hardware still supported by Microsoft or Apple respectively.  However, the Internet Protocol Suite ("TCP/IP") and the IEEE MAC layer are supported by the LAN irrespective of the machine environment.

Use the output of the relevant lsusb line's ID field (ID aaaa:bbbb) to look up the relevant kernel modules or install instructions. There is no single answer for all hardware.

user535733:  "lookup"  where?  The nominal manufacturer of the adapter offers no linux support and thus would not be the lookup source.

As of now,  assuming I get no more complete "answers" than "lookup", I am removing the referenced adapter and installing https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09GRL3VCN for which the claim is made (excerpt from above URL) "Plug & Play is enabled for Nintendo Switch, Windows 11/10/8.1, and Linux OS."  Presumably, "plug and play" in Linux means that the unit is auto-detected, installed, and activated at boot of Linux.  If not, I will be returning this other adapter under Amazon Prime for a full refund.  Note that the end-user will still have to arrange to have the (new) MAC address allowed by the LAN.

"lookup" at kernel.org to see when (or if) support for that hardware ID was added to the Linux kernel. Note that comments are not answers - most comments are intended to help you refine your question until it is answerable.

"Refine your question" is not a proper approach.  I have refined the question, and what is needed is a "cookbook flowchart" to address the issue.  My "question" is clear.  In my next comment, I shall provide my answer.

A working systems installation/configuration engineer simply does not have the time to "dig" for a possible solution with hardware that is not cleanly supported for Linux by the vendor.  The TP-Link USB to Ethernet Adapter (UE306), Supports Nintendo Switch, Foldable USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet LAN Network Adapter, Supports Windows, Linux referenced above was purchased.  The ethernet to USB adapter that Ubuntu 24.04 did not "see" was replaced by this newly purchased Linux plug and play adapter.  The LAN and WAN are now accessible from the computer, "problem solved".

The OP returned the incompatible j5create JUE130 to their vendor and used a different device instead that is compatible.
